# Find value for $m$ (gradient) so area above line is exactly half of the area under line

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Consider the values for $a=-1$, $b=2$ and $c=1$. How to find the gradient of the line $y=mx-abc$ passing through $y=(x+1)(x-2)(x-1)$?

Since $y=mx-abc$, substituting $a, b$ and $c$ we get $y=mx+2$.

Therefore, the line must pass through the $y$-intercept at $2$.

The question is to find a value of $m$ so that the area above $y=mx+2$ and contained by the curve $y=(x+1)(x-2)(x-1)$ is half the area bellow the line $y=mx+2$ and contained by the curve $y=(x+1)(x-2)(x-1)$.

Could someone help me with this please.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, it's a bit tricky to solve but nothing too hard I believe. What you have to do is find the intersection points between your line $y_1 = mx + 2$ and your curve $y_2 = (x+1)(x-2)(x-1)$. To do this, write $y_1 = y_2$ and solve for x. This result will depend on $m$.

Then you have to find in which case (between which solutions you just found) the line is above or below the curve, depending on whether $m$ is positive or negative.

And then you should integrate $|y_1 - y_2|$ in each domain to find the expression of the areas as a function of $m$. Writing that one area should be twice the other gives you one final equation, which you should be able to solve for $m$.